# how to create a aar library module whith dependent other aar file on gradle 8.0+

Tags: android, gradle, aar

For my project, I upgrade gradle to 8.0+, after that, I can't implementaion aar file properly.
i can only create a separate module and add aar file into this module, and then add to my project.

If I have multi aar files, I need to create multi modules, this is not a simple way. Does any guys know other ways?

refer to https://github.com/brim-borium/spotify_sdk/issues/99#issuecomment-878910598

it's ok for single aar, but if I want to create a aar module, and this aar module implement another aar, this way is not simple.

Comment: Please provide enough code so others can better understand or reproduce the problem.